# How to use PDO::FETCH_GROUP with a table join and only returning 3 records in a joined table ordered by date

Tags: php, mysql, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

I am using the following code to get a grouped list of voyage types and their respective voyages.

```
public function getVoyageTypesWithTrips() {
//query
$this->db->query('
SELECT voyagetype_name
     , voyagetype_description
     , voyagetype_image
     , voyage_id
     , voyage_name
     , voyage_startDate
  FROM voyagetypes 
  LEFT 
  JOIN voyages 
    ON voyagetypes.voyagetype_id = voyages.voyage_type
 WHERE voyagetype_deleted != 1
');


//get the results
$results = $this->db->resultSetGrouped();
return $results;
}
//get results set as array of objects - grouped
public function resultSetGrouped() {
$this->execute();
return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
}
```

What I want to do is limit the voyages table to only show the 3 most closest records to today instead of returning all the voyages for that type.

So returning

- Category 1 (Voyage next week, voyage week after, voyage week after that, no more but loads in table)
- Category 2 (voyage tomorrow, no more in this category)
- Category 3 (no voyages)

I initially tried ORDER BY and LIMIT but this doesn't work with the PDO::FETCH_GROUP I think.

I believe I need to have my SQL order & limit the joined table prior to sending to the fetch_group??? So something like

```
$this->db->query('
SELECT voyagetype_name
     , voyagetype_description
     , voyagetype_image
     , voyage_id
     , voyage_name
     , voyage_startDate
  FROM voyagetypes 
  LEFT 
  JOIN voyages 
    ON voyagetypes.voyagetype_id = voyages.voyage_type
APPLY THE SORT AND LIMIT TO THE JOINED TABLE
WHERE voyagetype_deleted != 1
');
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select vt.voyagetype_name, vt.voyagetype_description, vt.voyagetype_image, v.voyage_id, v.voyage_name, v.voyage_startdate
from voyagetypes vt
left join voyages v 
    on v.voyagetype_id = vt.voyage_type
    and (
        select count(*)
        from voyages v1
        where 
            v1.voyage_type = vt.voyage_type 
            and v1.voyage_startdate > v.voyage_startdate 
    ) < 3
where vt.voyagetype_deleted <> 1
```

Or, if you are running MYSQL 8.0, you can just use `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        vt.voyagetype_name, 
        vt.voyagetype_description, 
        vt.voyagetype_image, 
        v.voyage_id, 
        v.voyage_name, 
        v.voyage_startdate,
        rank() over(partition by vt.voyage_type order by v.voyage_startdate desc) rn
    from voyagetypes vt
    left join voyages v on v.voyagetype_id = vt.voyage_type
    where vt.voyagetype_deleted <> 1
) t
where rn <= 3
```

Comment: That was a fast answer. But it doesn't work. You'll get "subquery returns more than one row".

Comment: Now you won't get anything if there are less than 3 :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: yes I was thinking this through... I changed it again.